# iOS 12 safari can not prevent pinch scale with "touchmove" eventlistener when scrolling

Tags: safari, scale, pinch, ios12, touchmove

I add this code

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
    if (event.touches.length > 1) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
},
{
    passive: false
});
```

It worked when you don't move your page. But when you are scrolling the page and pinch scale the page at the same time, the page can still be scaling.

Is there any method to polyfill this situation?

Comment: I found this issue, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
const $body = document.querySelector('body');
$body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).